# Arduino IDE missing libread.s0.6

Tags: arduino-ide, avrdude, core-libraries

I just recently installed the ESP8266 libraries on the arduino IDE using the boards manager, the code compiles fine with the ESP, but when the board is changed to UNO, i get this error,

```
opt/arduino-1.6.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any solution to this?

Comment: You have to keep your software updated. Arduino IDE is currently in version 1.8.3.

Answer (score 1):

So install it?

```
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline6
```

Or, if you need the i386 version on an x64 platform:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline6:i386
```